# Comparing enum values using .equals() replaces the string being compared

Tags: java, string, equals

I have two classes: The main and the user classes.
In the main class I wish to print out all the female users. However, when I do the comparison it replace all the genders of the other users to female too

This is the user class

```
package com.user;

public class User {

    String name;
    static Gender gender;
    
    enum Gender{
        MALE,FEMALE
    }

    public User(String name, Gender gender) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public static Gender getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public static void setGender(Gender gender) {
        User.gender = gender;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("User [name= %s, gender= %s]", name,gender.toString());
    }
}
```

The main class

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
            
             {
                users.add(new User("Eva",Gender.FEMALE));
                users.add(new User("Mike", Gender.MALE));
                users.add(new User("Dave", Gender.MALE));
                users.add(new User("Alice", Gender.FEMALE));
            }
            
             users.stream()
                .filter(user -> Gender.FEMALE.equals(User.gender))
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
                .forEach(System.out::println);
        }
}
```

Please, where did I go wrong?

Comment: `gender` is `static`. I.e. there's only one field for the whole class. Make it non-static and replace `Users.gender` in your `filter` call with `user.gender`. Why is the `setGender` method written differently than the `setName`?

Comment: Also, as a side-note: you can skip the `.collect()` call if all you want to do is a `forEach`: streams have a `forEach` as well.

Comment: Also, you are not comparing `String`s, as your question suggests, you are actually trying to compare enum values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring the `gender` as a static member in your `User` class.

edit:

To make the solution more clear for you, and combining what other contributors wrote in comments:

```
public class User {

    String name;
    Gender gender;
```

and then

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
            
         {
            users.add(new User("Eva",Gender.FEMALE));
            users.add(new User("Mike", Gender.MALE));
            users.add(new User("Dave", Gender.MALE));
            users.add(new User("Alice", Gender.FEMALE));
        }
        
         users.stream()
            .filter(user -> Gender.FEMALE.equals(user.gender)) // user not User
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
            .forEach(System.out::println);
        }
}
```

Comment: `==` can be used to compare `Enum`s.  In fact that's what [`equals()` does](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/Enum.java#l135) under the hood.  I'm not saying that using `equals()` is wrong, just providing additional information.

Comment: Yes @Paul, thank you for the information, I did not know that.